# how to visualize nicely the WADLogsTable

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I am logging stuff into the azure tables (WADSLogsTable is the default) and it works fine.
My issue is: how do I visualize the logs in a nice way?

Until now I tried Azure Storage Explorer and Cerebrata's Azure Diagnostics Manager but I'm not impressed.

Any Ideas?

Comment: What are you looking for?  Those two tools are very nice (in my opinion - i use both).  There are other tools available too.  Is there a specific feature you're looking for and not seeing?

Answer (score 1):

Word "nice" is very subjective. I think the Cerebrata tools are top among others however if you have some better idea on how the log data should be display to help you better, share your thought. IF you are not satisfied with the available tools, i think it is good time to build one and share with community.

Comment: You are right, it would be nice to build a tool like tail or something. Maybe this weekend :)